# How can I avoid null pointer errors in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've got the following code:

```
const result = A.field_1.subfield_2
```

How can I evaluate result to `null` when `A` in null (or `A.field_1`) and avoid null errors? I was wondering if there's a more elegant approach rather than doing

```
if (A != null && A.field_1 != null) { ...
```

E.g., what if there're 10 fields.

Comment: `if (A != null && A.field_1 != null){}` ?

Comment: @CalvinNunes that makes sense, but I was wondering if there's a more elegant approach.

Comment: let y=A && A.field_1 && A.field_1.subfield_2

Comment: If you don't want to have to null check the whole way down, consider [lodash#get](https://lodash.com/docs/#get).  I wish there was a built-in way to do this, but there isn't right now.

Comment: The [optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) and [nullish coalescing](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing) proposals might be of interest to you. If you transpile your application with Babel, they [both](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator) have [plugins](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining) you can use.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(A && A.field_1 && A.field_1.subfield_2) {
  // Your code here
  // Remember: null and undefined always return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create custom method to check Object. Using object [**constructor**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) we can check weather a variable is object or not.

```
function isObject(obj) {
    return (!!obj) && obj.constructor === Object
}
const result = isObject(A) && isObject(A.field_1) ? A.field_1.subfield_2 : null
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a try/catch, works for 10 or more as well :)

```
try {
  const result = A.field_1.subfield_2
} catch(err) {
  // do something with the error
}
```

Comment: Exception handling shouldn't be used for control flow.  This is convenient, but its an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this a recursive function by looping over all of the [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and testing if they are valid or not using [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

The following function handles objects and arrays:

```js
function test(obj) {
  if (typeof obj == 'undefined' || obj == null) return false
  if (typeof obj == 'object') {
    return Object.values(obj).every(i => test(i))
  }
  return true
}

console.log(test({field_1: 0, field_2: 'abc'}))
console.log(test({field_1: 1, field_2: null}))
console.log(test({field_1: 1, field_2: null, cat: 123}))
console.log(test({field_1: 1, field_2: /abc/g, monkey: { dog: 'cat' }}))
console.log(test({field_1: 1, field_2: /abc/g, monkey: { dog: 'cat', mouse: { pig: null } }}))
console.log(test({field_1: 1, field_2: /abc/g, monkey: { dog: 'cat', mouse: { pig: [{cat: 'af'}]}}}))
console.log(test({field_1: 1, field_2: /abc/g, monkey: { dog: 'cat', mouse: { pig: [{cat: 'af'}, {cat: null}]}}}))
```